# How to share Image with some text using Intent code either on FB,Twitter in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, twitter

I have written this code and its successfully working its sending only content and it can share via FB,BlueTooth etc.But i want to share image as well.User will click on image and then   share button and save button will be shown.Now when user click on "share button" the clicked image must be share as Bluetooth,FB,Twitter etc.I have written this code its working for text please let me know how can i send image as well and images are inside the project folder @drawable folder....

```
public void shareApp()
    {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //setting MIME type for Sharing Content
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {"abc32@yahoo.com"});
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

    }
```